# Isomorphism of relative homology

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I have $2$ pair of chain complexes $(X_1,Y_1), (X_2,Y_2)$. And $$H_i(X_1,\mathbb Z) \cong H_i(X_2,\mathbb Z), H_i(Y_1,\mathbb Z) \cong H_i(Y_2,\mathbb Z).$$ Is it true that $$H_i(X_1, Y_1,\mathbb Z) \cong H_i(X_2,Y_2, \mathbb Z) ?$$ The first idea is to use $5$-lemma for the exact sequence of of homology. But I can't find homomorphism $$f: H_i(X_1, Y_1,\mathbb Z) \to H_i(X_2,Y_2, \mathbb Z),$$ commuting with isomorphisms of $$H_i(X_1,\mathbb Z)\ and\ H_i(X_2,\mathbb Z),\ H_i(Y_1,\mathbb Z)\ and\ H_i(Y_2,\mathbb Z).$$

UPD It isn't true. $X_1=Y_1=M, M$ is Möbius strip, $X_2=M=X_1, Y_2=S^1$ - the bound of M.

Comment: This won't be true unless the isomorphisms are induced by maps $(X_1,Y_1) \to (X_2,Y_2)$.

Comment: I can prove this fact. But i have no idea how to construct topological spaces(or even abstract algebraic complexes) for which relative homology are not isomorphic.